# Concept of jquery plugin methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm just starting of by making my own jquery plugins. I still havent wrapped my head around the concept of working with them and adding methods in the plugin and my recent attempt is failing and i dont know why. In this case bellow I got my regular piece of code i use to perform a capFirst and i want to transform that to the plugin..

**HTML**

```
<div id="contain">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**Original jquery**

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

$('#contain > input').keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.val(capitaliseFirstLetter($this.val()));
});
```

**My try of plugin code**

```
    (function($) {

    $.fn.capFirst = function () {        
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                var $this = $(this);    
                $this.val(methods.capitaliseFirstLetter($this.val()));
            });      
    };

    var methods = function () {       
        capitaliseFirstLetter: function(inputValue) {
              return inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);  
        } 
    };

})(jQuery);

$('#contain > input').capFirst();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypWTd/118/

**UPDATE**
working solution in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypWTd/163/

Comment: Why are you doing `$($(this))`? That just passes `this` into jQuery, and then passes the resulting object into jQuery again. Neither of which should be necessary!

Comment: You still don't need to pass `this` into jQuery. It will already be an instance of jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following section:

```
var methods = function () {       
    capitaliseFirstLetter: function(inputValue) {
          return inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);  
    } 
};
```

This actually causes a SyntaxError. You seem to mixing up the syntax between that required for an object literal, and that required for a "class" (an instance of which would need to be created with the `new` operator). If you just make it an object literal, rather than a function, it will work:

```
var methods = {       
    capitaliseFirstLetter: function(inputValue) {
          return inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);  
    } 
};
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypWTd/119/).

Also note that in your plugin method, `this` is already an instance of jQuery so you don't need to pass it in to jQuery again:

```
 $(this).keyup(function() {  //$(this)...
 this.keyup(function() { //Can just be this
```

**Update**

The other way (using a `function` instead of an object literal) would go something like this:

```
$.fn.capFirst = function () {
    this.keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this),  
            m = new methods(); //Create an instance of methods
        $this.val(m.capitaliseFirstLetter($this.val())); //Call the method
    });                  
};
var methods = function() {       
    this.capitaliseFirstLetter = function(inputValue) {
          return inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);  
    } 
};
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ypWTd/138/) of that version.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious difference is the double $($()) you are using for "this". Did you ever try to remove one of those $()?

Second: Usually you should "return this" to enable chaining.

Third: Usually you should provide support for multiple element selectors by using .each() inside the plugin

```
this.each(function() {
   $(this).keyup(...);
})
```

Fourth: You are trying to access a method of a class without using the "new" operator first. Either you should do

```
var myObject = {method: function() {...}}

myObject.method();
```

or you should instantiate the object first

```
var myObject = function() {
    function method() {
    }
}

var myInstance = new myObject();
myInstance.method();
```

Comment: if i do the return this.each(), how would my $('#contain > input').capFirst(); line be?

Comment: You can call the plugin the same way, the difference is that it returns the elements making it possible to use other functions/plugins on the same but updated object. Like `$('#contain > input').capFirst().myOtherPlugin().css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

#### This is how your plugin should be

```
jQuery.fn.capFirst = function () {
    $(this).keyup(function(){ 
        inputValue = $(this).val();
        inputValue = inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);
        $(this).val(inputValue);
    });                        
};

jQuery(function() {
    $('#contain > input').capFirst();   
});
```

## Check out the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypWTd/151/)

Comment: `$(this).keyup()` already refers to entire element selection so there´s no need to loop through all elements using `$.each()` and your plugin should return it´s received and modified elements to maintain chainability.

Comment: Yes, but each is needed because if not using each will result in "every textbox has the same text"

Comment: Oh damn, my fault. Thank you! I got this effect lately but this must be encountered by a other thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.capFirst = function () {
        return this.keyup(function() { // Returning the elements to maintain chainability
            var $this = $(this);    
            $this.val(methods.capitaliseFirstLetter($this.val()));
        });                  
    };

    var methods = { // Made this an object/array instead of a function that didn´t return anything.
        capitaliseFirstLetter: function(inputValue) {
            return inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.slice(1);  
        } 
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() { // Selectors should not be used before the DOM is ready.
    $('#contain > input').hide().capFirst().show().css('color', 'blue'); // Demo. chainability
});
```

jQuery documentation contains some good information about **[Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)**.

You´ll find my complete edit [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqFvh/).